# How to find the time complexity for a statement that is multiplied by i

Tags: pseudocode

I'm a student trying to analyze the time complexity of the following pseudocode fragment

```
function stars(A):
    for i in [1:n]:
        print ’*’ i many times
```

Shouldn't the time complexity for this be O(n)? There's only 1 'for' loop. The solution for it says its O(n^2).

Comment: the print method is also taken into consideration as n ... so n*n = O(N^2)

Comment: you mean when I actually print("*" * i) the print method has some internal loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your pseudo code

> print ’*’ i many times

means that the code performs an additional loop. This means that given `n` you print `n` times for every occurrences in [0, n]. Thus n * n which gives you the result O(n^2).

Comment: In python we can convert this loop into something like: for i in range(0,n): print("*" * i), which is just a statement, from what I understood, statements are only O(1). Still a little confused

Comment: A statement in your code noes not necessarily cost O(1). Assume for a moment that you agree that stars(A) costs O(n^2), the statement which you call stars(10) is a single statement, but it's complexity cost is O(n^2) even though it is a single statement. Is that a little bit clearer?